# Jersey declarative linking using JaxB adapter renders the link incorrectly

Tags: jaxb, moxy, jersey-2.0

I was trying to follow the declarative linking example:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22declarative-linking%22

Here is my code:

```
@InjectLink(   
        resource = FolderResource.class,  
        method = "query",   
        style = Style.ABSOLUTE,   
        bindings = {@Binding(name = "requestCount", value="99")   
        },   
        rel = "${rel}"  
)   
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Link.JaxbAdapter.class)
@XmlAttribute 
private Link href;
```

When I run it, i am getting this:

```
.....
       "href": "javax.ws.rs.core.Link$JaxbLink@41a741a7",
.....
```

instead of the actual link.

If I use a String type instead of Link and don't use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Link.JaxbAdapter.class), I am getting a correct link but without query parameters.

Advise, please.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same issue when trying to produce JSON output using MOXY. However, It works well when XML is set as Accept Header.

I wrote a MessageBodyWriter and MessageBodyRighter using Gson as the JSON provider. Unfortunately, this breaks the SelectableEntityFilteringFeature because this feature depends on MOXY.